# Programming in Visual Studio C

Tags: c

Command Line Always Print "Can Not Read" !!

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: E:\CTDL\1311370\Debug\1311370.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fclose.c
Line: 46

Expression: (stream != NULL)

```
#include "1311370_SearchA1s.h"
#include "1311370_SortA1s.h"

void main(){
    char fileIn[100], fileOut[100];

    printf("Enter Link of The Test File : ");
    flushall();
    gets(fileIn);

    printf("Enter Link of The Result Folder : ");
    flushall();
    gets(fileOut);
    strcat(fileOut, "\\1311370_BaiThucHanhSo1.txt");//nối thêm vào đường dẫn ghi file

    FILE * fin = fopen(fileIn, "r");
    FILE * fout = fopen(fileOut, "w");

    if (fin == NULL){
        printf("Can Not Read File\n");
        fclose(fin);
        fclose(fout);
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        char str[100], a[100], b[1];

        fgets(str, 100, fin);

        fprintf(fout , "Ex1Test1");

        fgets(a, 100, fin);
        fgets(b, 1, fin);

        int n = countSpace(a) + 1;
        int *array = convertStringToArray(a);
        int x = atoi(b);

        int pos = LSearch(array, n, x);

        fprintf(fout , "%d" , pos);

        delete array;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Mate. Please. C or C++? Which one? You chose to program in one of those languages? Which one did you pick in the end? (`delete` suggests C++, yes? Then why tag C?)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `char b[1];` isn't capable of holding any string except a `'\0'` string terminator. But `fgets()` retains the `'\n'` newline, so this is a case of putting "a quart into a pint pot". It doesn't leave `int x = atoi(b);` much to work with.

Answer (score 2):

The message seems pretty clear. It's telling you that, somewhere inside the implementation of `fclose`, there is a requirement (enforced by assertion) that the input not be `NULL`.

Indeed, if you read the *documentation* you'll see that `fclose` takes a `FILE*` that points to a stream, not a null pointer.

In your code you literally *only* call `fclose(fin)` when `fin` is `NULL`.The complete lack of logic in that aside, if you really want to write C++, there are *much* better ways to handle file I/O than this. Open your C++ book to the file I/O chapter and read on! Good luck.